# How to Stop Debugging in Visual Basic 2010 Express using a code?

Tags: vb.net, vb6

In Visual Basic 6.0, I can use the following code to stop debugging all of the forms:

```
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
Dim Form As Form
For Each Form In Forms
  Unload Form
  Set Form = Nothing
Next Form
End Sub
```

My question is: How to stop debugging all of the forms in Visual Basic Express 10 using a code similar with the above code? Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet without extra plumbing, VB-specific features, and to support forms created in other assemblies etc, is `Application.Exit`.